# For in Loops returning Array of each element in object

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

Write a function called getKeys. This function should: accept one argument, an object and return an array of each of the keys in the object
I also have to Write a function called getValues. This function should: accept one argument, an object and return an array of each of the values in the object
Here is what I have and I am am having trouble getting it to run:

```
 var getKeys = function(obj){
  var object = {name: "Lindsay"}
  for (var keys in object) {
  }
  return Object.keys(obj);
};
var getValues = function(value){
  var object = {age: 28}
  for(var keys in object) {
   }
  return Object.keys(value);

};
```

Comment: `function getKeys(obj) { return Object.keys(obj) }`

Comment: [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) ES2017 draft, not available on all platforms yet. However, you can just look at the polyfills.

Comment: What are those arguments for?

Comment: Thanks for the tips!! I tried that and it worked for the getKeys function, but I am still getting an error in the bottom half of the code. Any ideas? I edited the code I originally put to what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the keys is easy as we have Object.keys(obj); already, but you can wrap that as adeneo demonstrated.

Full example here

```
var myObj = {
    one: 'first',
    two: 'second',
    three: 'third'
};

function getKeys(obj) {
 return Object.keys(obj)
}

function getValues(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return obj[key]
 });
}

console.log(getKeys(myObj));//["one", "two", "three"]
console.log(getValues(myObj));//["first", "second", "third"]
```